# Table position forbidden

Tags: tables, positioning

I am editing a gigantic Latex file with multiple inclusions, so it is a bit unclear to me how this whole thing works. I got the error "!Latex Error: NOt in outerpar mode error" because table used [h!] position mode.

The table I tried to add is

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
A & B & C & D \\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
```

but I got the error in the title.

However if I replace `[h!]` by `[h]` or `[H]`, it works fine.

Does this mean there is some setting in the document that presents me from using the [h!]?

Comment: Usually you get the "not in outer par mode" error because you used the `table` environment inside a (maybe non-obvious) `minipage`, `\parbox`, or similar, or nested in another float. It shouldn't have anything to do with the positioning specifier. The only specifier that should make a difference here is `H`, as that doesn't use LaTeX's float mechanism at all, and can be put inside a `minipage`, etc..

Comment: replacing `[h!]` by `[h]` will not change the error.  But the error is where you have used the float (inside a box) not the option. `[H]` make it not a float so would remove the error as a accidental side effect

Comment: I do not get any errors using the code as is - -probably you have removed something based on assumption it is producing an error -- see this(https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/358397/197451)

Comment: @jsbibra yeah I know... see the two comments above. They explain the reason - think it is the same reason as in your link.